# How to recover files from Mircosof Teams group after being permanently deleted in recycle bins

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I am having trouble using the MS teams. As someone has deleted the recording file in the Files sections and must have permanently delete that file on the recycle bin of that group, is there any solution to recover that back up file ?

Comment: There is a second stage recycle bin available only to administrators. 
Have you checked that bin?

Comment: Is there anyway to recover if I am not the admin ?

Comment: Yes, its targeted at site collections admins only

Comment: If it's a O365 connected Site we are talking about you should become member of the O365 group owners and try again.

Comment: Or even simpler you could ask an administrator to check the second stage recycle bin for you ! :P :)

Answer (score 0):

You could go to recycle bin and to second stage recycle bin to recover deleted files. If files are deleted in the second stage recycle bin, there is no option to recover.

[image]

Comment: It's weird that my MS teams does not show anything about 2nd stage Recycle bin. Do you have any idea how to turn that on ? (It means that mine does not show the title Can't find what you're looking for ? Check 2nd stage recycle bin .)